# Открыть одну форму внутри другой VB NET

Tags: vb.net

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне внутри одной формы открыть другую дочернюю форму при нажатие пункта меню. Я хочу в своем маленьком проекте при выборе пункта меню Form1 открывалась другая форма Form2 внутри формы Form1. 
Покажите код.

Comment: Лучше сразу разместите на Form1 скрытую Form2, и по кнопке просто делайте её видимой.

Comment: А другой вариант есть. например есть свойства MDI parent или Children  просто я не смогла их использовать

Comment: Есть, как не быть-то... я просто предлагаю самый простой имхо в реализации способ.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim NewMDIChild As New yourchildformname() 

'установить Parent форму (текущая)
NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me

'Вызов дочерней формы
NewMDIChild.Show()
```